# What achievements or unlocks are only available by playing on Hard mode?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Edmund said [there will be  achievements for hard mode.](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/98202531689/isaac-the-hardening) What are they?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the Rebirth wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Achievements), which by no means claims absolute correctness but could be a nice indicator:

- God Head
- Lost Baby
- Cute Baby
- Crow Baby
- Shadow Baby
- Glass Baby
- Wrapped Baby
- Begotten Baby
- Dead Baby
- -0- Baby
- Glitch Baby
- Fighting Baby

All of them except for Godhead are for beating Mom's Heart in Hard Mode with various characters.

As for Godhead:

> Godhead is unlocked by beating the Chest, Dark Room and Boss Rush with The Lost.